# Database loop broken when I add substr, what's the error?

Tags: php, substr

I Have been creating this script for quite a while now, and I have ran into an error again. Here's the block of code.

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);    
while($query->fetch()):
     $lastspace = strrpos($body, ' ');?>
    <article>
    <h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
    <?php echo  $category;?>
    <?php echo "<br><br>";?>
    <p><?php echo nl2br (substr($body, 0, $lastspace)). "<br><a href='post.php?id=$post_id'>Read More</a>"?></p>
    <?php echo "<hr>"?>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

$db variable is the database connection.

The 'error' appears on the `php echo nl2br` line, After creating and adding the `substr`, `$lastpace` and the `href`, the `$body` won't echo. When I remove those the script runs and the while loop gets the `$body`.

I get no errors or anything, the `$body` will just refuse to show up.
Be noob friendly if it's possible :)
What's My error?

Comment: are you sure last space is always a number?

Comment: use error_log() to find the error

Comment: so what's the value of `$lastspace`? if there's no spaces in there, it'll evaluate to a boolean false, and php will `substr($body, 0, 0)`, effectively killing $body entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the `substr` and `nl2br` calls to avoid an error killing the loop. This way, if $body_sub is empty of null, nl2br will warn you, but not kill the script:

```
<?php
  $body_sub = substr($body, 0, $lastspace);
  echo nl2br($body_sub);
?>
```

Also, this is purely cosmetic, but your code looks cluttered. Why not have PHP echoing your HTML instead of inserting `<?php ?>` tags everywhere inside it?

Comment: The script has the same output as before, meaning that $lastspace isn't numeric? Hm, it should be according to my calculations

Comment: Try checking for it first, then: `if (!is_numeric($lastspace)) echo "Variable isn't numeric! Value is: ".$lastspace;`

Comment: Thanks mate, Got it working. Don't know what was the solution since I changed multiple things at once.